# jQuery and HTML, how to hide form based on value of another form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, templates

I have the need to hide a form based on value of another form using JavaScript.

Imagine that we have the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" id="one" >
         {{form.x|as_crispy_field}}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0 d-none" id="two">
         {{form.y|as_crispy_field}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, suppose that I want to hide the form y is x have the value equal to "Hide". How could get it using jQuery?

I have tried the following code, but It does not works:

```
       function check_field_value() {
           if($(this).val() == 'Hide') {
                $('#two').removeClass('d-none');
           } else {
                $('#two').addClass('d-none');
           }
       }

       // this is executed once when the page loads
       $(document).ready(function() {

           $('#one').change(check_field_value);
           check_field_value.call($('#one').get(0));
       });
```

**EDIT**

The Html about the form.y is the following:

```
<select name="y" class="select form-control" id="id_y">
  <option value="Hide">Hide</option>
  <option value="Not Hide">Not Hide</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't mix server-side code or templating code with html; JavaScript/jQuery acts on the resulting **HTML** - so **please** post the HTML. Exactly what form field of form x are you basing your `change` event on?

Comment: x it is a django field that woks exactly as a multiple choices (dropdown option form in HTML) and have only two possible status, "Hide" and "Not Hide"

Comment: Now it sounds like you have one form; more reason to show the **HTML**. Open the form in a browser and *inspect* the relevant elements and capture and post the relevant **HTML**. Thank you @Federico De Marco

Comment: Okey I follow your instructions and I have edited the answer.

Comment: @PeterKA could I ask you another issue?

Comment: in a private chat?

Comment: No problem @Federico De Marco

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214058/discussion-between-federico-de-marco-and-peterka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, as noted in comments, you are dealing here with two form elements and not two forms. You are using the correct form event but not targeting the right form element. Here is how you can do it:

```
$('#id_y').on('change', function() {
    if( this.value === 'Hide' ) {
        $('#one').hide();
    } else {
        $('#one').show();
    }
})
.change();
```

Demo:

```js
$('#id_y').on('change', function() {
    if( this.value === 'Hide' ) {
        $('#one').hide();
    } else {
        $('#one').show();
    }
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" id="one" >
         Some form element here
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0 d-none" id="two">
         <select name="y" class="select form-control" id="id_y">
            <option value="Hide">Hide</option>
            <option value="Not Hide">Not Hide</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

If your option elements were:

```
<option value="hide">Hide</option>
<option value="show">Not Hide</option>
```

Then your code would simply be:

```
$('#id_y').on('change', function() {
    $('#one')[this.value]();
})
.change();
```

Demo:

```js
$('#id_y').on('change', function() {
    $('#one')[this.value]();
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" id="one" >
         Some form element here
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0 d-none" id="two">
         <select name="y" class="select form-control" id="id_y">
            <option value="hide">Hide</option>
            <option value="show">Not Hide</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```